# What should I do if I notice water pooling outside of my shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, mold

We recently bought a home built in 2013.  Since moving in we have found that the master shower stall leaks.  In the month we have lived here we have noticed that the wall on both sides of the shower stall are discoloring from the floor up about 6 inches and that the linoleum floor is lifting at the shower stall edge.

What should we do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Find and fix the leak.  Probably lift the floor(possible replace) and dry out.  Apply bleach and clean the walls.  Adding pictures will let others give better answers.

Comment: Added pics for assistance

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Your question is too broad and needs to be focused on one specific issue. If you need assistance in finding the leak, please [edit] to focus on that. If you've found the leak and need to know how to fix it, please refocus the question on that. Once you've taken care of all that, then ask a new question about whether things can be fixed or need to be replaced. I've provided a _very generic_ answer to your _very generic_ question even though your question needs to be more focused.

Answer (score 1):

The standard answer for "what do I do when there's water where it shouldn't be" is:

1. Stop using the offending leak producing plumbing.
2. Find and fix the leak.
3. Dry, repair and replace as appropriate any water damaged materials.